# Как собрать несколько сводных таблиц в одну при помощи query

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Есть две исходных таблицы:

Из одной **Исход1** сделано 2 Сводных посредством query
Из второй **Исход2** сделана 1 Сводная также

Нужно получить итоговою таблицу в которую собрать 3 этих сводных и сделать дополнительные вычисления.
Перелопатил все что нашел по `query` и `arrayformala` но решение так и не нашел. Свести все надо по полю **Дата**.
Помогите пожалуйста
Прилагаю файл в котором есть все таблицы. Итоговую собрал руками для примера
[https://docs.google.com](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1g0ahH3lpCFLgRYLcAf2Onzpz4KBiHzi-zp_749XEBfc/edit?usp=sharing)